# Error 500 laravel after install

Tags: php, json, laravel

I installed LAMP on centos7 with php 7.
Then I installed Laravel using composer but I get error 500 in the browser and the following error in apache:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter in /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Mon$PHP 
Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter in /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php:34
Stack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php(42): Monolog\Formatter\\NormalizerFormatter->__construct(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractHandler.php(184): Monolog\\Formatter\LineFormatter->__construct()
#2 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractHandler.php(112): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractHandler->getDefaultFormatter()
#3 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(35): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractHandler->getFormatter()
#4 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Objec in /var/www/html/blog/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php on line 34
```

Can anybody please point me to the right direction?

Comment: this is quite old but this should work http://www.arckid.com/blog/amfphp/how-to-add-install-json-support-to-php-on-centos-in-10-steps/

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 5.3, 5.2, 5.1 ,5.0 and lower are not supported yet by PHP 7.

Hope newer version will support the php 7

Comment: This is utter nonsense. Laravel supports everything from php 5.6 up to the newest php 7.1. Their own development virtual machine (Homestead) is installed with 7.1 as default. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#server-requirements

Comment: I didnt say that it will not function at all, but there are many error, if you use with php7. In my case i am having problem for some of my projects, so i am saying it by practice and not by what they are writing there.

Comment: I've used php 7 and 7.1 for each Laravel release since 5.1 and haven't encountered any problems. Maybe you pulled in a dependency that isn't compatible yet with php 7+?